# cakePHP redirect to blank page only in online domain but localhost working good

Tags: php, redirect, cakephp

I'm using redirect method in cakePHP to navigate from page to another and in add page when I press submit button it should send data to database and redirect to index view but it didn't and show in URL it's going to samePage/add but it should go to just samePage, not samePage/add again.

This issue happened only on online version but in localhost, everything does well.

I'm using the same code on all pages

```
 return $this->redirect('/Boardmembers');
```

it works online but only on one page.
All the pages except this boardmembers page when I redirect it's going to blank age and on URL pageName/add again.

I'm trying another format of typing URL in redirect method like

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Boardmembers','action' => 'index'));
```

but no one working except boardmembers page.

and this error only in online domain

Comment: Do you have the same config/routes.php file on both localhost and server?

Comment: yes, the same file on both.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is removing all whitespace before PHP start and end tag ""